# Looking for a real continuous differentiable Function that is non-conformal

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis

My Question builds upon following Proposition:

> Let $G$ be a region in $\mathbb{C}$. The following statements about a
> real continuous differentiable Function $f: G \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$
> are equivalent:
>
> i) $f$ is holomorphic on $G$ and $f'(z)\neq 0$ on $G$
>
> ii) f is angel preserving (conformal) on $G$

Does anyone have a good example of a real continuous differentiable Function the is not angel preserving.

Comment: The proposition tells you that pretty much anything that's real-differentiable but not complex-differentiable will be an example. So take anything that's not too hard to write down but doesn't satisfy the Cauchy-Riemann equations. For example, $\bar z$, $\operatorname{Re}(z)$, $\operatorname{Im}(z)$, and most differentiable functions applied to any of these will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take any linear map $A : \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ that is not conformal, i.e. that is not a multiple of an orthogonal matrix. Since the Frechet derivative is $DA(x) = A$, this example works.